# How can I display local storage data only when a certain date is selected?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

This is a table reservation that I'm trying to make and I'm trying to display the reservations and layout for a selected date - and only the ones made for that date.

At the moment it saves them to local storage but when I change the date it doesn't display them. When I change dates it just shows the static layout and reservation that I made in the JSON file. It shows that for every date it will reset the reservations and layout I made but I can still see them in the local storage.

app.vue:

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="left-container">
      <DateFilter :selectedDate="selectedDate" @input="selectedDate = $event" />
      <div class="numberinput">
        <label for="numRows">Rows:</label>
        <input type="number" v-model="numRows" id="numRows" />
        <br>
        <label for="numSeats">Seats per Row:</label>
        <input type="number" v-model="numSeats" id="numSeats" />
        <button @click="addRowsAndSeats">Add Rows and Seats</button>
      </div>
      <table class="reservedTables">
        <td colspan="6">
          <input style="
          width: 100px; 
          height: 25px;
          flex-direction: column;
          align-items: center;
          border-style: ridge;
          border: 1px solid #ddd;
          border-radius: 5px;" type="text" v-model="filterText" placeholder="search" />
        </td>
        <tr style="font-weight: bold;">
          <th>Tisch</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Datum</th>
          <th>Von</th>
          <th>Bis</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
        <tr v-if="filteredItems.length > 0" v-for="(reservation, index) in filteredItems" :key="index">
          <td>{{ reservation.box }}</td>
          <td>{{ reservation.name }}</td>
          <td>{{ reservation.date }}</td>
          <td>{{ reservation.startTime }}</td>
          <td>{{ reservation.endTime }}</td>
          <td class="centered-button">
            <button style=" 
            padding: 3px 6px;
            background-color: rgb(244, 90, 90);
            color: #ffffff;
            border: solid 1px grey;
            cursor: pointer;" @click="toggleBox(reservation.box)">X</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="popup" v-if="showReservationPopup">
      <span class="close" @click="closeReservationPopup">&times;</span>
      <div class="popup-content">
        <label for="reservationName">Name:</label>
        <input v-model="reservationName" id="reservationName" placeholder="Name" />
        <br>
        <label for="reservationTime">Uhrzeit:</label>
        <input type="time" v-model="reservationStart" id="reservationStart" />
        <input @blur="validateTime" type="time" v-model="reservationEnd" id="reservationEnd" />
        <input @click="checkboxhalf()" id="checkBoxHalf" v-model="isCheckedhalf" class="check" type="checkbox" />
        <label for="checkBoxHalf" style="margin:-4rem;">12 Stunden</label>
        <br>
        <input @click="checkbox()" id="checkBoxFull" v-model="isChecked" class="check" type="checkbox" />
        <label for="checkBoxFull" style="margin:-4rem;">24 Stunden</label>
        <button @click="makeReservation();">Reservieren</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="right-container" style="background-color:rgb(242, 224, 244);width: auto;height: auto;border-style:groove;">
    <div class="container-wrapper">
      <div class="table-row" v-for="(row, rowIndex) in rows" :key="rowIndex" @mousedown="startDrag(rowIndex, $event)"
        @mouseup="endDrag" ref="tableRows">
        <table class="table">
          <tr>
            <td v-for="(box) in row" @click="openReservationPopup(box, rowIndex)" class="box"
              :class="{ yellow: isReservationYellow(box), red: isReservationRed(box) }" id="draggable" draggable="true">
              {{ box }}
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  import DateFilter from './datefilter.vue';
  import ReservationData from "./reservation.json";

  export default {
    components: {
      DateFilter,
      ReservationData,
    },
    data() {
      return {

        rows: [
          [1, 2, 3, 4]
        ],
        filterText: "",
        isDragging: false,
        draggedRowIndex: null,
        isDragging: false,
        offsetX: 0,
        offsetY: 0,
        numRows: 1, // Default number of rows
        numSeats: 4, // Default number of seats per row
        selectedDate: new Date(), //sets date to current day
        reservations: [],
        selectedRow: null,
        showReservationPopup: false,
        selectedBox: null,
        reservationName: null,
        reservationStart: null,
        reservationEnd: null,
        originalEndTime: null,
        isChecked: false,
        isCheckedhalf: false,
        activeBoxes: Array(12).fill([]), // Initialize an array for tracking active boxes
        ButtonPositionX: '0px',
        ButtonPositionY: '0px',
        rows: [
          []
        ],
      };
    },
    watch: {
      // Watch for changes to the selectedDate and update the layout and reservations
      selectedDate(newDate) {
        console.log('Selected Date Changed:', newDate);
        this.loadLayoutAndReservations();
      },
    },
    methods: {
      async loadLayoutAndReservations() {
        try {
          const response = await fetch('/src/reservation.json'); // Adjust the path to your JSON file
          if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
          }
          const data = await response.json();

          if (data && data.layout && data.reservations) {
            // Update the layout and reservations based on the fetched data
            this.rows = data.layout.rows;
            this.reservations = data.reservations;

            // Initialize this.activeBoxes with empty arrays
            this.activeBoxes = Array(this.rows.length).fill([]);
          } else {
            // Handle the case where data is not available or the structure doesn't match
            console.error('Data not found or invalid format');
            // You can choose to clear the layout and reservations or show an error message
            this.rows = [];
            this.reservations = [];
            this.activeBoxes = [];
          }
        } catch (error) {
          // Handle any errors that occur during the data fetching process
          console.error('Error loading layout and reservations:', error);
          // You can choose to clear the layout and reservations or show an error message
          this.rows = [];
          this.reservations = [];
          this.activeBoxes = [];
        }
      },

      checkboxhalf() {
        if (!this.isCheckedhalf) {
          this.reservationEnd = "20:00";
          this.reservationStart = "08:00";
        } else if (this.isCheckedhalf) {
          this.reservationEnd = "";
          this.reservationStart = "";
        }
      },
      checkbox() {
        if (!this.isChecked) {
          this.reservationEnd = "23:59";
          this.reservationStart = "00:00";
        } else if (this.isChecked) {
          this.reservationEnd = "";
          this.reservationStart = "";
        }
      },

      addRowsAndSeats() {
        // Create new rows and seats based on user input
        const newRows = [];
        // Generate numbers for the new boxes starting from the last box number + 1
        let currentNumber = 1;
        if (this.rows.length > 0) {
          currentNumber = this.rows[this.rows.length - 1][this.rows[this.rows.length - 1].length - 1] + 1;
        }
        for (let i = 0; i < this.numRows; i++) {
          const newRow = [];
          for (let j = 0; j < this.numSeats; j++) {
            newRow.push(currentNumber++);
          }
          newRows.push(newRow);
        }
        // Append the new rows to the existing rows
        this.rows = [...this.rows, ...newRows];
        // Update activeBoxes to match the new structure
        const newActiveBoxes = new Array(this.numRows).fill([]).map(() => []);
        this.activeBoxes = [...this.activeBoxes, ...newActiveBoxes];
        console.log(this.rows);
      },
      toggleBox(box) {
        // Find the index of the selected reservation
        const index = this.reservations.findIndex((reservation) => reservation.box === box);
        if (index !== -1) {
          // Remove the reservation from the reservations array
          this.reservations.splice(index, 1);
        }
        // Find the row and column of the selected box
        for (let row = 0; row < this.rows.length; row++) {
          const rowIndex = row;
          const colIndex = this.rows[row].indexOf(box);
          if (colIndex !== -1) {
            // If the box is found in the activeBoxes array, remove it
            const boxIndex = this.activeBoxes[rowIndex].indexOf(box);
            if (boxIndex !== -1) {
              this.activeBoxes[rowIndex].splice(boxIndex, 1);
            }
            // Update the cell background color to the default color
            this.rows[rowIndex], colIndex, box;
            break; // Exit the loop once the box is found
          }
        }

      },

      isReservationYellow(box) {
        const reservation = this.reservations.find((reservation) => reservation.box === box);
        if (reservation) {
          const start = new Date(`2000-01-01T${reservation.startTime}`);
          const end = new Date(`2000-01-01T${reservation.endTime}`);
          const duration = (end - start) / (1000 * 60 * 60); // Duration in hours
          const isYellow = duration <= 12; // Check if duration is 12 hours or less
          if (isYellow) {}
          return duration <= 12; // Return true if duration is 12 hours or less
        }

        return false;
      },

      // Check if a reservation should be highlighted red
      isReservationRed(box) {
        const reservation = this.reservations.find((reservation) => reservation.box === box);
        if (reservation) {
          const start = new Date(`2000-01-01T${reservation.startTime}`);
          const end = new Date(`2000-01-01T${reservation.endTime}`);
          const duration = (end - start) / (1000 * 60 * 60); // Duration in hours
          return duration > 12; // Highlight red if duration is more than 12 hours
        }
        return false;
      },
      openReservationPopup(box, row) {
        // Check if the box is not active (red)
        if (!this.isReservationRed(box)) {
          this.selectedBox = box; // Store the selected box
          this.selectedRow = row;
          this.showReservationPopup = true; //sets it to true so it pops up
        }
      },
      //resets everything when closing the popup
      closeReservationPopup() {
        this.selectedBox = null;
        this.showReservationPopup = false;
        this.reservationName = '';
        this.reservationStart = "";
        this.reservationEnd = "";
        this.isChecked = false
        this.isCheckedhalf = false

      },
      makeReservation() {
        if (!this.reservationName || !this.reservationStart || !this.reservationEnd) {
          alert('Name and Uhrzeit are required fields.');
          return false;
        }

        // Check if the selected table is already reserved for the same date and time
        const existingReservation = this.reservations.find((reservation) => {
          return (
            reservation.box === this.selectedBox &&
            reservation.date === this.selectedDate &&
            this.doTimesOverlap(reservation.startTime, reservation.endTime, this.reservationStart, this.reservationEnd)
          );
        });

        const rowIndex = this.rows.findIndex(row => row.includes(this.selectedBox));

        if (existingReservation) {
          alert('Dieser Tisch wurde schon reserviert!');
        } else {
          // Initialize this.activeBoxes[rowIndex] as an array if it's undefined
          if (!this.activeBoxes[rowIndex]) {
            this.activeBoxes[rowIndex] = [];
          }

          // Push the selectedBox into this.activeBoxes[rowIndex]
          this.activeBoxes[rowIndex].push(this.selectedBox);

          // Create a reservation object
          const reservation = {
            box: this.selectedBox,
            name: this.reservationName,
            date: this.selectedDate,
            startTime: this.reservationStart,
            endTime: this.reservationEnd,
          };

          // Push the reservation into the array
          this.reservations.push(reservation);
          this.saveData();

          // Close the popup
          this.closeReservationPopup();
        }
      },

      // Check if two time ranges overlap
      doTimesOverlap(start1, end1, start2, end2) {
        const startTime1 = new Date(`2000-01-01T${start1}`);
        const endTime1 = new Date(`2000-01-01T${end1}`);
        const startTime2 = new Date(`2000-01-01T${start2}`);
        const endTime2 = new Date(`2000-01-01T${end2}`);

        return (
          (startTime1 <= startTime2 && startTime2 < endTime1) ||
          (startTime2 <= startTime1 && startTime1 < endTime2)
        );
      },

      formatDate(date) {
        const year = date.getFullYear();
        const month = String(date.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
        const day = String(date.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
        return `${year}-${month}-${day}`;
      },

      saveData() {
        // Save layout and reservations data to localStorage
        localStorage.setItem('layout', JSON.stringify({
          rows: this.rows
        }));
        localStorage.setItem('reservations', JSON.stringify(this.reservations));
      },
    },
    mounted() {
      // Set the initial date to today's date (or any default date)
      const today = new Date();
      this.selectedDate = this.formatDate(today);
      this.loadLayoutAndReservations();

      // Retrieve data from localStorage
      const savedLayout = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('layout'));
      const savedReservations = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('reservations'));

      // Only update the data properties if the data is not empty
      if (savedLayout && savedLayout.rows && savedReservations) {
        this.rows = savedLayout.rows;
        this.reservations = savedReservations;
      }
    },
    computed: {
      filteredItems() {
        const filterText = this.filterText.toLowerCase();
        return this.reservations.filter((reservation) =>
          reservation.name.toLowerCase().includes(filterText) ||
          reservation.date.toLowerCase().includes(filterText) ||
          reservation.startTime.toLowerCase().includes(filterText) ||
          reservation.endTime.toLowerCase().includes(filterText) ||
          reservation.box.toLowerCase().includes(filterText)
        );
      },
    }

  };

  @import './js.css'; 
</style>
```

datefilter.vue:

```html
<template>
    <div class="date-filter">
        <div v-if="selectedDate" class="date">
            <button style="margin-right: 10px;" @click="changeDate(1, 'previous')">Previous Day</button>
            <input type="date" v-model="selectedDate" @change="dateChanged" />
            <button style="margin-left: 10px;" @click="changeDate(1, 'next')">Next Day</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {

    data() {
      return {
        currentDate: new Date(),
        selectedDate: this.formatDate(new Date()),
      };
    },
    methods: {
      changeDate(days, direction) {
        const newDate = new Date(this.selectedDate);

        if (direction === 'previous') {
          newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() - days);
          this.currentDate.setDate(this.currentDate.getDate() - days);
        } else if (direction === 'next') {
          newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + days);
          this.currentDate.setDate(this.currentDate.getDate() + days);
        }

        this.selectedDate = this.formatDate(newDate);

        // Emit the selectedDate when it changes
        this.$emit('input', this.selectedDate);
      },
      dateChanged(event) {
        // If the input is not a valid date, don't update the selectedDate
        if (!event.target.checkValidity()) {
          return;
        }

        this.selectedDate = event.target.value;
        // Emit the selectedDate when it changes
        this.$emit('input', this.selectedDate);
      },
      formatDate(date) {
        const day = String(date.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
        const month = String(date.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
        const year = date.getFullYear();
        return `${year}-${month}-${day}`;
      },
    },

  };
</script>
```